# SSRS Chart Group Series - How do I get the secondary series group to start at the first data point?

Tags: reporting-services, charts, rdl

I have a chart where I am comparing two years worth of data. I have a series group that filters the data for each year.

The problem is that the secondary group series is not starting at the first data point.

Is there a parameter I can set to get this working?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working after starting with a new chart. I believe there was a setting that I was overriding in the nonworking chart. I will post the problem when I find out just in case anyone else has the same issue.